# Have one observable wait for the second one while having the second one just get the last emitted value from the first observable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have two observables which I use to update a list. One of them gets the items in the list and the other one gets their states, then I create the actual list with the items having their corresponding states.

Let's call them observable **A** and **B**

**A** emits the items. --a--b--c-->

**B** emits their states. --a_true--b_false--c_true-->

**B** doesn't have access to the actual items, only their Id, so I need both observables.

The first time I wait for both **A** and **B** to emit their first batch of items and then I process them and send them to the list.

whenever **A** emits a new batch, I need an update from **B** in order to get the new items' states

**B** can update the states at any given moment, and as long as **A** has updated the items at least once, it can just use the last batch and update their states.

What is the best way to do this? I have some experience with RxJava but I can't seem to find an elegant way to do this with the available operators.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here and what the output is. You could use a `ConcurrentHashMap<Id, Record>` and have each `Observable` add or update to it whenever there is an event.

Comment: @akarnokd I basically have this setup already. However, whenever I get new records I need their states to be updated. When I get new states for the records, I don't really need the records to be updated.

Comment: The combineLatest operator may be useful http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html. For the B observable you may use repeatWhen http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/repeat.html to retreive states again when A emits some new information

Comment: yeah! that's exactly what I needed. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.